# Angular production release - dependency version mismatch with QA

Tags: angular

I am done with an Angular app development and trying to deploy the same in to production.

I have executed this command: ng build --prod --environment=prod. This creates a package in dist folder. In package.json, I use ^ with dependency versions. This way, it will take the latest patch version to build the release package.

Lets say, during QA, a dependent package version was 1.0.0. Then before prod release, a new patch 1.1.0 released for this dependency. So if I follow ^ approach, there can be different dependency versions in QA & Prod. Is specifying exact versions with no ^ the only solution for this? Any other better ways to handle this?

Comment: I think better use fixe version in prod and development because. The relative version is good practice for open source project, but in the real project, you need to build a good business and development process. It means that you must be sure in your  code that you deploy on the prod. That's why before every update of the package you need decide,  need you this update now and how many relative packages you need the update with it. Ad what it can break. And you need test your application after that.

Comment: I think it's be better if you build the package once, or at the same time for QA and prod, to make sure they are as close as possible. Also, maybe have a look at package-lock.json and npm shrinkwrap if you don't want to use fixed versions